# Why are there strange backspace characters in my WPF datagrid?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Our software uses the DataGrid throughout its user interface for displaying editable lists. While editing some metadata, I wanted to remove the text in a particular column for many rows. This is pretty quick if you get into the rhythm of F2-Backspace-Enter, F2-Backspace-Enter, F2-Backspace-Enter….

Things don’t go quite so well if you miss the F2 part of the pattern and just press Backspace-Enter on a cell. The WPF DataGrid will actually replace the contents of the cell with the backspace character. Depending on how you look at your string, this might show up as 0×08, , \u0008, or \b.

What on earth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This CodePlex post](http://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/10246?ProjectName=wpf) confirms a bug in the DataGrid and includes some workarounds. On our end, the current fix is simply to ignore strings that have a backspace character in them. This way they don’t end up in the XML, which is good because in XML 1.0 the backspace is an illegal character.

See also this [Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/625773/backspace-in-a-cell-in-the-wpf-datagrid-produced-b-in-the-text).

Comment: Microsoft Connect (as linked) also notes that this issue has been fixed in WPF 4.5